# VBA code to take some string components, search them inside a workbook and replace the components with the cell addresses found

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I am having a column in excel with formulas that return TRUE/FALSE. The component of each formula are alphanumeric strings that starts always from ABC_ and always ends in 7 digits. The middle part of the string may vary.

For example =OR(ABC_XYZ_0001234 >0 , ABC_XYZ_0001235 <0).

These alphanumeric strings indicate cells from an other workbook. I want to replace these strings with the cell address that this string is found.

For example =OR('[Wrkbook.xlsx]Sheet1'!$A$39 >0 , '[Wrkbook.xlsx]Sheet1'!$A$40 <0).

The strings are unique inside the destination workbook.

I tried the following code with no success:

```
Sub FindStringInOtherWorkbook()

Dim strSearch As String
Dim rng As Range
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim c As Range
Dim rplce As String

'Set the range to search in the active sheet
Set rng = ActiveSheet.Range("A")

'Open the second workbook
Set wb = Workbooks.Open("C:\path\to\Wrkbook.xlsx")

'Loop through each sheet in the second workbook
For Each ws In wb.Sheets
    'Loop through each cell in the range
    For Each c In rng
        strSearch = c.Value
        'Search for the string in the current sheet
        Set c = ws.Cells.Find(What:=strSearch, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
        'If a match is found, return the cell address
        If Not c Is Nothing Then
            rplce = Replace (rng, rplce.Value, c.Address)
        End If
    Next c
Next ws

'Close the second workbook
wb.Close

End Sub
```

Comment: what does "no success" actually mean?

Comment: no running at all. no errors, just no running

Comment: it's impossible. what do you get when you debug it?

Comment: Is ABC_XYZ_0001234 a named range or a string ? If it were a string the formula would be `=OR("ABC_XYZ_0001234" >0 , "ABC_XYZ_0001235" <0)` which doesn't make sense.

Comment: ^^^ after you deal with the quotation mark issue, what doesn't make sense is that after you've done the replacements, your Formulas will contain references to cells that contain strings, which you compare to 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First search the wrkbook for all ABC_* values and store address in a dictionary. Then scan down the column using a regular expression to extract the ABC_ strings and using the dictionary replace string with address.

```vb
Sub FindStringInOtherWorkbook()

    Const FOLDER = "" ' "C:\path\to\"

    Dim wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet
    Dim dict As Object
    Dim rng As Range, c As Range, fnd As Range, first As Range
    Dim f As String, n As Long
   
    ' dictionary
    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    
    'Open the second workbook and extract ABC_ addresses
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(FOLDER & "Wrkbook.xlsx")
    For Each ws In wb.Sheets
        With ws.UsedRange
           Set fnd = .Find("ABC_*", LookIn:=xlValues, lookAT:=xlWhole)
           If Not fnd Is Nothing Then
                Set first = fnd
                Do      
                   'Debug.Print fnd.Value, fnd.Address(0, 0, xlA1, True)
                   If dict.exists(fnd.Value) Then
                       MsgBox "Duplicate Key " & fnd.Value & vbLf & dict(fnd.Value) _
                       & vbLf & fnd.Address(0, 0, xlA1, True), vbExclamation
                       Exit Sub
                   Else
                       dict.Add fnd.Value, fnd.Address(0, 0, xlA1, True)
                   End If
                   
                   Set fnd = .FindNext(fnd)
               Loop Until fnd.Address = first.Address
                   
           End If
        End With
    Next
    
    ' regular expression
    Dim regEx As Object, m As Object
    Set regEx = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    With regEx
        .Global = True
        .MultiLine = False
        .IgnoreCase = True
        .Pattern = "(ABC_.*?\d{7})"
    End With
        
    'Set the range to search in the active sheet
    Set rng = Workbooks("Book1.xlsx").Sheets("Sheet1").UsedRange.Columns("A")
    For Each c In rng.Cells
        f = c.Formula
        If regEx.test(f) Then
           For Each m In regEx.Execute(f)
               s = m.submatches(0)
               If dict.exists(s) Then
                   f = Replace(f, s, dict(s))
                   n = n + 1
               End If
           Next
           c.Formula = f
        End If
    Next
    MsgBox n & " replacements made", vbInformation
    
    'Close the second workbook
    wb.Close

    ' debug code dump dictionary
    Dim k, i
    Workbooks.Add
    i = 1
    For Each k In dict.keys
        Cells(i, 1) = k
        Cells(i, 2) = dict(k)
        i = i + 1
    Next

End Sub
```